# Keydown event not working in listview

Tags: vb.net, listview, keydown

This is my code for keydown:

```
 If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
        'find the item to be selected
        lvBranch.FindItemWithText(txtFind.Text, True, 0, False).Selected = True 
    End If
```

when I press enter, it's not working, but when I do a test like msgbox when I press enter, it works. The code is for selecting the record in the listview that matches the value of txtFind.

Thank you in advance

Comment: so are you saying, msgbox will work but the line of 'lvBranch.FindItem...' does not work?

Comment: i think the `lvBranch.FindItemWithText(txtFind.Text, True, 0, False).Selected = True ` is your problem here.

Comment: @Rex: yes sir that line

Comment: @LeonardDrapeza: yes sir it does not work in keydown but in button event its working.

Comment: so the keydown event is for txtFind, right? can you set a breakpoint at this line and check the value of txtFind.Text? it sometimes does not give the value you expect...

Comment: ok sir i will try this, tnx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is working, all you need is to send **focus** to the **lvBranch**

This code should be in **KeyDown** event for **txtFind**

```
If e.KeyCode = Keys.Enter Then
    Dim Result As ListViewItem = lvBranch.FindItemWithText(txtFind.Text, True, 0, False)
    If (Not Result Is Nothing) Then
        lvBranch.Focus()
        Result.Selected = True
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

If your listview is in a form with KeyPreview = True then the KeyDown Handles for your ListView does not process the ENTER Key